# How to deduce type of a derived class

Tags: c++, class, templates

Lets say I have a base abstract class:

```
class Base  
{
 public:
 virtual ~Base(){};
 };
```

and derived from it template class:

```
template<typename T>
class Derived : public Base 
{
 public:
    void function(); 
};
```

And another class Test, which has vector of Base class objects

```
 class Test
 {
 public:
 vector< Base* > base_vector;
 };
```

QUESTION 1: If we have a vector of pointers to objects of Base class, they can also be filled with pointers to Derived classes, right?

So, lets say now I access this vector from already existing test class, which was previously filled with pointers to objects of Derived class type

```
void (Test test)
{
    vector<Base*> objects = test.base_vector;
}
```

QUESTION 2: Is it possible to deduce the typename of the Derived objects, which pointers point to? (Derived class is a template)

OR Is it possible to call function() which was defined in Derived class, and dont care about type of the Derived class ?

If not, what are the minimal changes that should be made to any of these classes?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what your problem is? `Is there a way to deduce type of Derived classes` doesn't really make sense.

Comment: "Obviously this class also accepts Derived classes as well" ... you better read about object slicing, because placing a `Derived` into a vector of `Base` might not have the effect that you expect

Comment: To have a polymorphic vector (with objects of derived classes) it has to contain pointers rather than objects.

Comment: Make some example with something that is better to grasp, like class Dog : public Animal or class Boat : public TransportationDevice. Then describe what you want to achieve, like "I want to build a vector<Animal*> that collects all animals in a zoo and then collect the sum of the food they need". Point is, we need to see your design. It should not happen too often that you should need to known the exact class of something if you work on it's base class. I assume that you are somewhat new to this concept.

Comment: That said, there are two major things for you: 1.: variable or class names are something you as the programmer uses but that are not used by the computer. As soon as you compile, they are gone. 2.: You can always put in a method that returns something related to the type. Like "virtual static AnimalType get_animal_type() const;" in the base class Animal, with AnimalType being some enumeration or a string or some other way to store a type, and every sub class overwriting that method with something like "AnimalType Dog::get_animal_type() const { return dog; }".

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly then you need to use virtual functions. If you want to call a function on the objects and make sure that the function of the correct type is called then make your `function` virtual. So you need to declare it in your `Base` class. Also, you need to make your vector be a vector of pointers to `Base`. Then when you call your `function` on the objects of the vector it will call the function from the derived class if the objects are indeed of the derived type.

This way you don't need to find out the type of the objects, you'll just call the virtual function and it will find out what type of object it is and call the correct function.

Comment: But what if I can't make any changes to the base class ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understood what you want, but will this modification of your code work for you? This way you either do not need to deduce type at all, or you can get a virtual `type()` method, that will return you an enum with some unique value for every type.

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
  virtual void function() = 0;
  virtual ~Base() = default;
};

template <class T> class Derived : public Base {
public:
  void function() override {
      // to produce some output
      std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl; 
  }
};

class Test {
public:
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> objects;
};

int main() {
  Test test;
  test.objects.push_back(std::make_unique<Derived<int>>());
  test.objects.push_back(std::make_unique<Derived<std::string>>());
  for (auto &ptr : test.objects) {
      ptr->function();
  }
}
```

Alternative solution to this problem is to use a `variant` class, for example [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/variant.html), or std::experimental::variant (if you standard library already has one). This way you don't need to have `virtual function()` in Base class. `boost::variant` has `which()` method that returns you and integer number of type in a type list. An example:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Base {
public:
  virtual ~Base() = default;
};

template <class T> class Derived : public Base {
public:
  void function() {
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
  }
};

class Test {
public:
  std::vector<boost::variant<Derived<int>, Derived<std::string>>> objects;
};

int main() {
  Test test;
  test.objects.push_back(Derived<int>());
  test.objects.push_back(Derived<std::string>());
  for (auto& obj : test.objects) {
    switch (obj.which()) {
      case 0:
        boost::get<Derived<int>>(obj).function();
        break;
      case 1:
        boost::get<Derived<std::string>>(obj).function();
        break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first solution is very legit! However, what if the Base class is so substantial, that you just can't make any changes to it?

Comment: @AlexShirokov well, you can just try to upcast it to Derived<T> with dynamic_cast: `if (auto derived = dynamic_cast<Derived<int>>(ptr.get())) { ptr->function(); }`. It will return nullptr, if the object is of an incompatible type (ie not Derived<int> or derived from it). Note however that such code will become messy soon, it's much cleaner just to add function to the base class.

Comment: @AlexShirokov If somebody uses a pointer to the base class somewhere, then by this he states that he wants exactly what the base classes interface provides. If he wants something in addition, like a function that returns a type, then the base class is not what he wants to use. Using tricks to circumvent that is code smell. What one could do is creating a class that is in between and provides the correct interface, from which then the sub classes are derived and of which type the pointer is. Of course, in any case, such things should be decided in some realistic context.